# How to create a apex test class for my apex class

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

It is my first apex class and i don't really know how to implement a proper test class. 
My goal is to achieve test coverage of 75%.

I updated based on the comments but i managed to achieve only 70 %. I don't have other idea how to improve this more.

Here is what i did :

Apex class:

```
 public with sharing class AccountController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> findAll() {

    User userDetails =[SELECT Id, Name, Email, Profile.Name, UserRole.Name FROM User
        where Id=:userinfo.getUserId() ];

    // Theme4t is theme that is used by mobille app for  android or iphone 
    if(((userDetails.UserRole.Name).equals('yon')|| (userDetails.UserRole.Name).equals('bon')|| (userDetails.UserRole.Name).contains('non')
        || (userDetails.UserRole.Name).contains('go')) && UserInfo.getUiTheme() != 'Theme4t'){
       return [SELECT id, name, AccountStatus__c, ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude, ShippingCity
        FROM Account
        WHERE ShippingLatitude != NULL AND ShippingLongitude != NULL 
        LIMIT:22000];

    }else {
       return [SELECT id, name, AccountStatus__c, ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude, ShippingCity
        FROM Account
        WHERE OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND ShippingLatitude != NULL AND ShippingLongitude != NULL 
        LIMIT:5000]; 

    }
}
```

Apex test class:

```
 @isTest 
public class AccountControllerTest 
{
static testMethod void testMethod1() 
            {
                           Account acc = new Account();
                           acc.Name='Test';

                           insert acc;
                           User userDetails =[SELECT Id, Name, Email, Profile.Name, UserRole.Name FROM User
        where Id=:userinfo.getUserId() ];


                          List<Account> lstAcc = AccountController.findAll();
                          UserRole ur =new UserRole();


                         userDetails.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name='yon'].Id;
               System.runAs(userDetails){
                          List<Account> lstAcc1 = AccountController.findAll();  

               }

               userDetails.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name='bon'].Id;
               System.runAs(userDetails){
                          List<Account> lstAcc2 = AccountController.findAll();  

               }

                userDetails.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name='non'].Id;
               System.runAs(userDetails){
                          List<Account> lstAcc3 = AccountController.findAll();  

               }

               userDetails.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name='go'].Id;
               System.runAs(userDetails){
               List<Account> lstAcc4 = AccountController.findAll();  

               }                       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please complete the below trailhead to learn the unit test in Salesforce.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

And also as you are trying to create a user after account insertion it will throw Mixed DML error. you need to use system.runAs() method. follow the below URL for using the method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Let me know if still, you need any help on this.

Here is the code for your class and test class. Please follow the best practices from http://blog.shivanathd.com/2013/11/Best-Practices-Test-Class-in-Salesforce.html
This time I am providing the code to you to understand how to create a test class, but next time onwards please follow the steps and documents I have shared.

```
public with sharing class AccountController { 
            //using a test visible variable for setting the ui theme check.
            @TestVisible static Boolean isTheme4t = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme4t';
            @AuraEnabled
            public static List<Account> findAll() {

                User userDetails =[SELECT Id, Name, Email, Profile.Name, UserRole.Name FROM User  where Id=:userinfo.getUserId()];

                // Theme4t is theme that is used by mobille app for  android or iphone 
                if(((userDetails.UserRole.Name).equals('yon')|| (userDetails.UserRole.Name).equals('bon')|| (userDetails.UserRole.Name).contains('non') || (userDetails.UserRole.Name).contains('go')) && !isTheme4t){
                    return [SELECT id, name, AccountStatus__c, ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude, ShippingCity FROM Account WHERE ShippingLatitude != NULL AND ShippingLongitude != NULL LIMIT 22000];

                }else {
                    return [SELECT id, name, AccountStatus__c, ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude, ShippingCity FROM Account WHERE OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND ShippingLatitude != NULL AND ShippingLongitude != NULL LIMIT 5000]; 
                }
            }
 }




    @isTest 
    public class AccountControllerTest 
    {
        //Use setup data method to create data and query it in testmethod 
        @testSetup static void setup() {
            UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'yon', Name = 'yon');
            insert r;
            User u = new User(
                ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id,
                LastName = 'last',
                Email = 'puser000@amamama.com',
                Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                CompanyName = 'TEST',
                Title = 'title',
                Alias = 'alias',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                UserRoleId = r.Id
            );
            insert u;
            System.runAs(u){
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                acc.ShippingLatitude = 75.46;
                acc.ShippingLongitude = 45.46;
                acc.AccountStatus__c = 'test';
                insert acc;
            }
        }

        static testMethod void testMethod1(){
            user u = [select Id from User where email = 'puser000@amamama.com' limit 1];
            system.runAs(u){
                Test.startTest();
                List<Account> acc = [select Id,AccountStatus__c,ShippingLatitude,ShippingLongitude from Account where Name = 'Test Account'];
                List<Account> lstAcc4 = AccountController.findAll();  
                system.assert(lstAcc4.size()>0);
                Test.stopTest();

            }
        }
        static testMethod void testMethod2(){
            user u = [select Id from User where email = 'puser000@amamama.com' limit 1];
            system.runAs(u){
                AccountController.isTheme4t = true;
                Test.startTest();
                List<Account> acc = [select Id,AccountStatus__c,ShippingLatitude,ShippingLongitude from Account where Name = 'Test Account'];
                List<Account> lstAcc4 = AccountController.findAll();  
                system.assert(lstAcc4.size()>0);
                Test.stopTest();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the answer with the class code and test class code. Understand this class and from next onwards try to follow the same with steps and documents I have shared. If this helps you please mark it the best answer. Thanks

Comment: It is almost good 72%. The problem is that i can not change the user role. It is possible to change it in the test method ?  I tried something like this but  is no working.                           
            user u = [select Id from User where email = 'testuser000@amamama.com' limit 1];
            UserRole r = new UserRole( Name = 'lol');
            insert r;
            u.UserRoleId = r.Id;                                                                                      
            runAs(u)...

Comment: It is 100% if you use the same code I provided for class and Test class. Why do you want to change the user role? it is already there which you required for your code, which is "Yon". any of the one should be there.